# Saving Excel worksheets as separate files and looping through folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, vba

How can I separate all the Excel files in a folder into separate sheets?

All the files have two sheets called results and datapoints.

I'm using VBA in Excel.

```vb
Sub LoopThroughFilesAndSplit()
    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xFdItem As Variant
    Dim xFileName As String
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xFdItem = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
        xFileName = Dir(xFdItem & "*.xlsm*")
        NewFileName = Left(xFileName, Len(xFileName) - 5)
        Do While xFileName <> ""
            With Workbooks.Open(xFdItem & xFileName)
                Dim FPath As String
                FPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
                Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
                    ws.Copy
                    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & NewFileName & "-" & ws.Name & ".xlsx"
                    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
                Next
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            End With
            xFileName = Dir
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

It's only working on the sheet I'm putting the code into and isn't looping through the folder.

If anyone knows how to do this in Python, that's the platform I wanted to learn. I couldn't find any template for this purpose.

Comment: Before doing it in Python, it is advisable to decide in which way (win32com.client (COM), [Python Excel libraries](https://www.excelpython.org/) ...) and in which operating system it should be done

Answer (score 1):

Try this VBA code

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughFilesAndSplit()
    Dim xFd As FileDialog, xFdItem As Variant, xFileName As String, NewFileName As String, ws As Object
    
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        xFdItem = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
        xFileName = Dir(xFdItem & "*.xlsm*")
        Do While xFileName <> ""
            NewFileName = Left(xFileName, Len(xFileName) - 5) 'move inside loop
            With Workbooks.Open(xFdItem & xFileName)
                For Each ws In .Sheets  'remove ThisWorkbook so will be used `With Workbooks.Open`
                    ws.Copy
                    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=.Path & "\" & NewFileName & "-" & ws.Name & ".xlsx"
                    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
                Next
                .Close False    'close opened `With Workbooks.Open`
            End With
            xFileName = Dir
        Loop
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```